# Is it ok for Google to ad few Breadcrumb Schema to header?

Tags: schema, schema.org

I mean few scripts. I have this structure to add:

website/secondary_a_1
website/secondary_a_2

website/primary_a_1
website/primary_a_2

So my schema right now is like this this:

{
"@context": "https://schema.org/",
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
"itemListElement": [{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 1,
"name": "Name1",
"item": "website/secondary_a_1"
},{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 2,
"name": "Name2",
"item": "website/secondary_a_2"
}]
}

And another script:

{
"@context": "https://schema.org/",
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
"itemListElement": [{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 1,
"name": "Name1",
"item": "website/primary_a_1"
},{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 2,
"name": "Name2",
"item": "website/primary_a_2"
}]
}

I use "primary" and "secondary" just to tell that there are 2 differrents services and folder with their own subpages.

Is it ok for GOogle and SEO to have same schema in different scripts??

Comment: This is not JSON Schema.

Comment: It was created on Merkle Schema Generator. When i was posting script tags had been removed for some unknown reason.